# Why my YII need have installed Oracle's Instant Client libraries?

Tags: yii, oci8

I am playing with Yii framework and now I am investigating Yii Shell. But if I use this command:

yiic shell

I always get this error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Error: index.php does not exist or is not an entry script file.
```

It is strange for me, because I am gonna to use only mySQL drivers, so why Oracle now? Any idea?

Many thanks for your replies!

Jakub

Comment: I can't think of what Yii should have anything to do with this unless you recently installed PDO and for some reason PHP is trying to load all the drivers. Check your php.ini file in the extensions section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install Oracle client and Open your `php.ini`, search for `oci8.so` and `php_oci.so`, in extensions section you should have something like `extension=oci8.so` and `extension=pdo_oci.so`, just comment it with `;`. If You have `extension=oci8_11g.so` comment it as well"

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini, search for oci8.so and php_oci.so, in extensions section you should have something like `extension=oci8.so` and `extension=pdo_oci.so`, just comment it with `;`. If You have `extension=oci8_11g.so` comment this as well